# Parent-Child MOCs and default attribute values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a private NSManagedObjectContext (self.moc) with parent another private NSManagedObjectContext.
When running the code it works well on my device. However, one of the beta testers complained about an issue and when I looked at the logs he had sent me, I noticed that the code is always running something it shouldn't be executing at all!

```
//operations start from here
var lastModifiedDate: NSDate = self.dayLog.lastModified

//...do some operations (all the operations here don't touch the self.dayLog)
//saving the self.moc 

self.moc.refreshObject(self.dayLog, mergeChanges: true)

if lastModifiedDate != self.dayLog.lastModified {
   //most probably we shouldn't get here more than once
   lastModifiedDate = self.dayLog.lastModified
   //...restart operation from beginning
   //One of the beta tester is always running this chunk
}
```

Note that DayLog is a NSManagedObject and DayLog.lastModified is a CoreData date attribute with default value 01/01/2001.

Comment: What values do `lastModifiedDate` and `self.dayLog.lastModified` have when your code compares them?

Comment: No idea! I forgot to add logs to this part. I will try to add some logging here to found out what it's going on.